# Displaying variable in rails view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

If I have variable that looks like this

```
[{"value"=>"4"}]
```

When I put inspect in view like this:

```
<%= @res.inspect %>
```

How do I show/print/echo only it's value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this one

```
<%= @res.first["value"] %>
```

or

```
<%= @res[0]["value"] %>
```

Answer (score 2):

## Ruby 2.3 and newer

`@res` is an Array with a Hash at index 0. To get the value, you can use :

```
@res.dig(0,"value")
```

And to display it in a view :

```
<%= @res.dig(0,"value") %>
```

Using [`dig`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Hash.html#method-i-dig) is the safest variant here, because it won't raise an exception if the array is empty.

## Older Ruby

For older Ruby versions, you can use :

```
<%= @res.fetch(0,{}).fetch("value") %>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try:

```
<% @res.each do |item| %>
  <p><%= item["value"] %></p>
<% end %>
```

It would be useful while you'll have more items in your array.